# ref, computed alternatives in vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

I did a project in Vue 3 and I used `ref` and `computed`. Then I realized that I was supposed to do the project in Vue 2... and now I get : "export 'computed' was not found in 'vue'
"export 'ref' was not found in 'vue' ... I know that I need Vue 3 for those, that s why i want to ask if there are any alternatives:

this is where I use ref and computed:

```
  import { ref, computed } from "vue";

  export const collapsed = ref(false);
  export const toggleSidebar = () => (collapsed.value = !collapsed.value);

  export const SIDEBAR_WIDTH = 180;
  export const SIDEBAR_WIDTH_COLLAPSED = 38;
  export const sideBarWidth = computed(
    () => `${collapsed.value ? SIDEBAR_WIDTH_COLLAPSED : SIDEBAR_WIDTH}px`
  );
```

and here also:

```
  import { computed } from 'vue'
  import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
  import { collapsed } from './state'

  export default {
    props: {
      to: { type: String, required: true },
      icon: { type: String, required: true }
    },
    setup(props) {
      const route = useRoute()
      const isActive = computed(() => route.path === props.to)
      return { isActive, collapsed }
    }
  }
  </script>

  <template>
      <router-link :to="to" class="link" :class="{ active: isActive }" >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`computed`](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) is also in vue 2, but in vue 2 you need to use options api :

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      collapsed: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    toggleSidebar() {
      return this.collapsed.value = !this.collapsed.value
    },
    sideBarWidth() {
      return `${this.collapsed ? SIDEBAR_WIDTH_COLLAPSED : SIDEBAR_WIDTH}px`
    }
  }
}

export default {
  props: {
    to: { type: String, required: true },
    icon: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  computed: {
    isActive() {
      return this.$route.path === this.to  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, how can I use now collapsed and the methods toggleSidebar and SidebarWidth in other files, import doesn't work

Comment: i am new to vue

Comment: @palalele hey mate, are you using vuex? You can use vuex or you can use mixins

Comment: i heard about vuex, but i dont really know a lot about it.... if I use vue x  can i do this easier?

Comment: sorry mate I need more info, what do you try to do with your app?

Comment: so I try to do a Sidebar / sidepanel and I watched a tutorial how to do one. I did it all good, but in vue 3... I need it to be compatible with vue 2, because my project's buddies use boostrap-vue ....

Comment: codeshare.io/sidebar-vue

Comment: https://codeshare.io/sidebar-link

Comment: https://codeshare.io/state

Comment: here is the code

Comment: so where else do you need methods and data from state? you can create one template and put all there

Comment: i need it in sidebar https://prnt.sc/kCjDZ6quXZqL and sidebar link https://prnt.sc/X_DtcoboMmcp    and here when I click on the button that toggles the sidebar https://prnt.sc/ej_NoSSveHZw

Comment: ok, then you can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/)  or you can move all 3 into sidebar component

Comment: ok and if a move all 3 inside sidebare component, how can I get the collapsed property from sidebar to use in sidebar link?

Comment: you can paste your files for sidebar [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/palalele-6wm02v) and I will try to convert them to vue 2

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/palalele-forked-ltrv09

Comment: ok, you saved only sidebar pls add link and button

Comment: is not really a button,is the bar that I click that is toggling the sidebar https://prnt.sc/rJszQrCHNx-d

Comment: ok no problem just copy all needed files (ones that use methods, dat for sidebar) and I will write here when I finish converting, must go now but tonight I will solve that for you :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/palalele-forked-9my20z

Comment: `this.$router.path` should be `this.$route.path`, @Nikola. `$router` does not have a `path` property. To get it from `$router` you'd need to use `this.$router.currentRoute.path`.